# Given that $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$ and $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$, try to find $f$

Tags: functional-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ and $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/fx1-fx1-and-fx2-fx2)

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for all reals $x$
$f(x^2)=f(x)^2$ and $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$

Can we show that $f(x)=x$ for all reals $x$? Do we need additional assumptions in order to prove that $f(x)=x$ for all reals $x$ (like continuity, differentiability or monotony)? If so, try to give an example of a function $f$ different from $f(x)=x$ that satisfies all the stuff above.