# Find all real functions which satisfy $xf(x+y)+f(y)=f(y)f(x+1)+f(x^2)$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ which satisfy:
>
> $xf(x+y)+f(y)=f(y)f(x+1)+f(x^2)$

\begin{align}
& \text{let } P(x, y): xf(x+y)+f(y)=f(y)f(x+1)+f(x^2). \\
P(0, y): \; & f(y)=f(y)f(1)+f(0). \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(y)(1-f(1))=f(0). \\
\text{ if } \; & f(1) \neq 1: \\
& f(y)=c, xc+c=c^2+c, c=0 \rightarrow \boxed{f \equiv 0}. \\
\text{if } \; & f(1)=1: f(0)=0.\\
P(x, 0): \; & xf(x)=f(x^2).
\end{align}

Here's my attempt and effort, but can't do somethin' else. Can anyone help me solve this F.E.?

(This problem is from Olympiad similarities collection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $f(1) \neq 0$ already grants $f \equiv 0$ with what OP already did, so let's look at the case $f(1) = 1$.

Thanks to $f(0) = 0$ showed by OP, we have:
$$P(-1, y):\quad -f(y - 1) + f(y) = f((-1)^2) = f(1) = 1$$
As such, by taking $y+1$ instead of $y$:
$$\forall y \in \mathbb{R},\quad f(y +1) = f(y) + 1 \tag{$1$}$$
Therefore $P(x,y)$ is equivalent to: $xf(x+y) = f(y)f(x) + f(x^2)$.
Afterwards:
$$P(x,0):\quad xf(x) = f(x^2)$$
Since $x^2 = (-x)^2$, this gives: $xf(x) = f(x^2) = -xf(-x)$, and thus, as we already have $f(0) = 0$:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad f(x) = -f(-x) \tag{2}$$
Using $(2)$, we get:
$$P(x, -x):\quad 0 = -f(x)^2 + f(x^2)$$
Hence:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad f(x^2) = f(x)^2 \tag{3}$$
But thanks to the post [$f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ and $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57928/1104384) we can conclude that this would imply $f = \operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R}$ since it satisfies $(1)$ and $(3)$.

Finally, $0$ and $\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R}$ are solutions, and as such we have found all the solutions of OP's equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$xf(x+y) + f(y) = f(y) f(x+1) + f(x^2)$$

1. Put, $x = 0$, $$f(y) = f(y) f(1) + f(0) \implies f(y) = f(0)/(1-f(1))$$
   OR $f(1) = 1$ and $f(0) = 0$,
2. Put $y = 0$, $xf(x) = f(x^2) \implies$
   Putting $x \rightarrow -x$ in the this equation, $-xf(-x) = f(x^2) = xf(x) \implies f(x) = -f(-x)$. So $f$ is an odd function.
3. Look at $$f(y^2) = yf(y) \rightarrow f(y^2) = y f((\sqrt{y})^2) = y^{1+0.5} f(y^{0.5}) \implies$$ $$ f(y^2) = y^{1+\sum_i \frac{1}{2^i}} \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(y^{\frac{1}{2^i}}) = y^2 f(1) = y^2$$,

Hence $f(y^2) = y^2$ and coupled with odd property of function, we have $f(y) = y$.

In the above we have assumed continuity of $f(x)$ at $x = 1$.

4. Only Solution, is $f(x) = x$ OR $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: This would have been a cool solution if continuity had been assumed, so I'll still give a +1, but as shown in my answer you don't actually need to assume continuity.